# Getting the xslt "stack"

Tags: javascript, php, xml, templates, xslt

I have an xsl template:

```
<xsl:template name="xsl-error-message">
    <xsl:element name="script">
        <xsl:text>console.error(&quot;There is an error.&quot;);</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

it may be called from anywhere else in the transform, in order to "throw" an error message . The error message takes the form of a script (javascript) tag using the `console.error()` javascript function.

Now, I would like to also display the "stack trace" that lead to this template. Let's say this was the calling templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="foo"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="foo">
    <xsl:call-template name="xsl-error-message"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like the `<script>` tag to have the following javascript code inside:

```
console.log('There is an error. Callers: <xsl:template match="/"> --> <xsl:template name="foo"> --> <xsl:template name="xsl-error-message">');
```

**So I want to retrieve which templates called the `xsl-error-message` template, and put this "trace" in the javascript code.**

If I cannot do so, is there a way to make it easier to debug XSLT, and give hints about which template called the `xsl-error-message` template?

Or is there some way to use the PHP XsltProcessor (or any other PHP5+ built-in xsl processor) to help debugging and find which template called which other one? I saw `setProfiling()` method but I didn't find a way to get some kind of stack (I can see in the profiling log file that the `xsl-error-message` has been called, but I don't know which template called it).

Comment: Debugging client-side XSLT in the browser is difficult but there are XML or XSLT IDEs like Stylus Studio or Oxygen that have debuggers.

Comment: I have no idea what this is about, but you can always call a template with a parameter.

Comment: For sure, use a true XSLT debugger where you can step, set breakpoints, see the call stack, evaluate variables and debug on the fly ... oXygen, Stylus, Altova.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Oh gosh... hum... Okay, interesting but totally out of my budget! Actually, I also "accept" ways using PHP's XsltProcessor since I can apply the xslt on server-side. Any idea?

Comment: IMHO, you would spend untold dollars in time and effort even attempting to do what $350 buys you. So, no ideas for you, sorry, except maybe google "free XSLT debugger" and see what that leads to. Never used any of them.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, Saxon has an extension function to output a stack trace:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/saxon/print-stack

However, like all Saxon extensions, this requires Saxon-PE or higher, which means you're going to have to find a few pennies.